# Is it possible to automate saving event viewer errors as text files?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, event-viewer

I currently spend a considerable amount of time copying and pasting event viewer logs into text files and then copying them to a repository on another computer.

Is it possible to automate the saving these event viewer logs between a specified date/time to the computer (so that they can then be copied to the repository).

Ideally, if it's possible, it has to be achieved by C# .NET code.

The purpose of this is for automated tests, which run on Windows Server 2003/2008 machines.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`EventLog.GetEventLogs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.geteventlogs.aspx) will get you the logs, you can then loop throught them and write to a text file. The example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74e2ybbs.aspx) will get you started.

Comment: Brilliant thanks! 

I was also able to find the other EventLog methods [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0acz16ca.aspx), which provide plenty of other helpful functions such as the ability to clear the event log (which I could do before running tests).